# REDIS Slave unable to connect Master

Tags: azure, redis, ubuntu-16.04

Redis slave is unable to connect to the Redis master.
We have redis setup on Azure servers.

Following is the redis log,

```
    Connecting to MASTER MasterIP:6379
 * MASTER <-> SLAVE sync started
 * Non blocking connect for SYNC fired the event.
 * Master replied to PING, replication can continue...
 * Partial resynchronization not possible (no cached master)
 * Master does not support PSYNC or is in error state (reply: -ERR Can't SYNC while not connected with my 
 * Retrying with SYNC...
 # MASTER aborted replication with an error: ERR Can't SYNC while not connected with my master
```

Also find the MASTER redis connection at exactly at the time slave connection is lost,

```
* Background saving terminated with success
# Connection with slave  IP:6379 lost.
# Connection with slave  IP:6379 lost.
# Connection with slave  IP:6379 lost.
# Connection with slave  IP:6379 lost.
# Connection with slave  IP:6379 lost.
# Connection with slave  IP:6379 lost.
# Connection with slave  IP:6379 lost.
# Connection with slave  IP:6379 lost.
# Connection with slave  IP:6379 lost.
# Connection with slave  IP:6379 lost.
# Connection with slave  IP:6379 lost.
# Connection with slave  IP:6379 lost.
# Connection with slave  IP:6379 lost.
# Connection with slave  IP:6379 lost.
# Connection with slave  IP:6379 lost.
* SLAVE OF **UNKNOWN IP**:8888 enabled (user request)
* Connecting to MASTER **UNKNOW IP**:8888
* MASTER <-> SLAVE sync started
* Non blocking connect for SYNC fired the event.
* Master replied to PING, replication can continue...
# Unable to AUTH to MASTER: -Reading from master: Connection timed out
```

Here, master automatically tries to connect to some unknown IP.

How can I debug this more?

Comment: Are you sure your Master is in role:master? See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11307356/how-to-know-master-slave-status-of-redis

Comment: I have the same problem

Answer (score 0):

```
# Replication
role:slave
master_host:xxx.xx.xx.xxx
master_port:xxxx
master_link_status:up
master_last_io_seconds_ago:6
master_sync_in_progress:0
```

1. use command 'info' to check replication status of redis slave, make sure role is slave
2. check if master_link_status is up, if down, there may be two causes:
   (1) I/O error trying to sync with MASTER:connection lost
   change the buffer limit using `config set client-output-buffer-limit ‘slave 512mb 128mb 120’`([client-output-buffer-limit](https://redis.com/blog/top-redis-headaches-for-devops-replication-buffer/)) or change the config file
   (2) Unable to AUTH to MASTER: -ERR Client sent AUTH, but no password is set
   change password if not correct